# IronPython.Runtime.UnboundNameException: 'global name 'sin' is not defined' error

Tags: python, ironpython

I am having a problem with iron python script when I am trying to use math function sin.

```
var pyForSrc = @"def Test():
                 return sin(a)";
```

As I am trying to execute the above script then getting the error.

```
IronPython.Runtime.UnboundNameException: 'global name 'sin' is not defined'
```

I tried using math.sin(a); also but then I got error like below

```
IronPython.Runtime.UnboundNameException: 'global name 'math' is not defined'.
```

I am getting error also when I tried to add like Math.sin(a);
can someone help me how can I add math library to the IronPython Script?

Comment: Have you included the math module?

Comment: Sorry How to include the math Module. I read about it this math module is always vailable.I am using the ironpython nuget pacakage(v2.7.9)

Comment: Write 'import math' at the top of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write:

```py
import math
```

at the top of your code